# How to make something like the spreadsheets of Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make something like the spreadsheets of Excel, where I can add and insert more columns and rows so that prestored information could be added with no problem.

Thus, any type of numerical function or number could be inserted in between the empty boxes or spaces. So that, for example, I could add, subtract, multiply, or divide the numbers even if we insert more numbers in between or at either ends.

could somebody tell me how should i start it, what approach i should follow to make it in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

I assume at minimum you need an in place editable grid so you can move the cursor/focus with the arrows keys or mouse and type in content...

for this there are many grid components you can use, like DevExpress ASPxGridView (http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/asp/grid) or Telerik.

it depends also if you work in normal web forms or MVC, I find those controls are usually more advanced and mature for the web form platform.

There are also pure excel like controls, like this FarPoint one, we use it in our Windows Forms applications: [FarPoint Spread for ASP.NET](http://www.fpoint.com/netproducts/spreadweb/spread.aspx)

if you absolutely want to stay on the freeware, have a look at some of those JQuery grids available online.